# Decrypt Word document knowing part of its content

Tags: encryption, ms-word

I have a ciphered .docx document I would like to recover and I don't remember the password. I'm trying brute-forcing it but it's taking way too long, so it's not going to be option. However, I know the exact content of part of it (296 characters). Any help?

Comment: The point of proper encryption is even if you know part of the decrypted text it does not help you get the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, part of the document wouldn't help.

To get to the cleartext, any cracker would still need to go through trying to crack the password hash that is exported from the document, and with your logic try to decrypt the file and interpret it's content, compare it to the known cleartext. There is no such funcitonality, especially for specialized document formats.

Here is an example how to approach it:

Document: encrypted_doc.docx

Password: 123horse123
You will have to use office2john to export the hash to be cracked from the document.

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/bleeding-jumbo/run/office2john.py

python office2john.py encrypted_doc.docx > doc_pass_hash.txt
cat doc_pass_hash.txt 
encrypted_doc.docx:$**office$*2013***100000*256*16*e77e386a8e68462d2a0a703718febbc9*08ee275ccf4946ae0e5922e9ff3114b7*0ab5fc00964f7ed4be9e45c77a33b441b2c4874d28e4bc30f38e99bfb169fcf4
```

Remembering some information about the password(complexity, some chosen words if any, character set etc.) [mask attack](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mask_attack) could help you run a more effective way to uncover the document.

Run hashcat --help to see which document file are you dealing with:

```
   9700 | MS Office <= 2003 $0/$1, MD5 + RC4               | Documents
   9710 | MS Office <= 2003 $0/$1, MD5 + RC4, collider #1  | Documents
   9720 | MS Office <= 2003 $0/$1, MD5 + RC4, collider #2  | Documents
   9800 | MS Office <= 2003 $3/$4, SHA1 + RC4              | Documents
   9810 | MS Office <= 2003 $3, SHA1 + RC4, collider #1    | Documents
   9820 | MS Office <= 2003 $3, SHA1 + RC4, collider #2    | Documents
   9400 | MS Office 2007                                   | Documents
   9500 | MS Office 2010                                   | Documents
   9600 | MS Office 2013                                   | Documents
```

Based on what you can recall from the password, you can choose from the following:

```
  - [ Attack Modes ] -

      # | Mode
     ===+======
      0 | Straight
      1 | Combination
      3 | Brute-force
      6 | Hybrid Wordlist + Mask
      7 | Hybrid Mask + Wordlist
```

Here are the options for hashcat to specify the password:

```
?l = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
?u = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
?d = 0123456789
?h = 0123456789abcdef
?H = 0123456789ABCDEF
?s = «space»!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
?a = ?l?u?d?s
?b = 0x00 - 0xff
```

You can also create your own dictionary, which then will be used when generating the passwords, if you remember at least part of the password. This can be the most efficient help.

So in my example, let's run a brute force attack with mask(3 digits, 5 alphabetical characters, and another 3 digits):

```
hashcat -m 9600 -a 3 doc_pass_hash.txt --username -o cracked_pass.txt ?d?d?d?l?l?l?l?l?d?d?d --force
```

You can hit [s] for status:

```
[s]tatus [p]ause [b]ypass [c]heckpoint [q]uit => s

Session..........: hashcat
Status...........: Running
Hash.Type........: MS Office 2013
Hash.Target......: $office$*2013*100000*256*16*e77e386a8e68462d2a0a703...69fcf4
Time.Started.....: Sat May 30 16:59:30 2020 (3 mins, 41 secs)
Time.Estimated...: Next Big Bang (17614 years, 157 days)
Guess.Mask.......: ?d?d?d?l?l?l?l?l?d?d?d [11]
Guess.Queue......: 1/1 (100.00%)
Speed.#1.........:       21 H/s (7.50ms) @ Accel:128 Loops:32 Thr:1 Vec:8
Recovered........: 0/1 (0.00%) Digests, 0/1 (0.00%) Salts
Progress.........: 4608/11881376000000 (0.00%)
Rejected.........: 0/4608 (0.00%)
Restore.Point....: 0/1188137600000 (0.00%)
Restore.Sub.#1...: Salt:0 Amplifier:9-10 Iteration:24672-24704
Candidates.#1....: 623anane123 -> 612kerin123
```

As you see, this one doesn't seem to be very effective (`Time.Estimated...: Next Big Bang (17614 years, 157 days)`), however, adding a wordlist is a good idea:

```
cat wordlist.txt
dog
horse
cat


hashcat -m 9600 -a 6 doc_pass_hash.txt wordlist.dict ?d?d?d?l?l?l?l?l?d?d?d --username -o cracked_pass.txt --forces

Session..........: hashcat
Status...........: Running
Hash.Type........: MS Office 2013
Hash.Target......: $office$*2013*100000*256*16*e77e386a8e68462d2a0a703...69fcf4
Time.Started.....: Sat May 30 17:15:34 2020 (1 min, 25 secs)
Time.Estimated...: Next Big Bang (734631 years, 226 days)
Guess.Base.......: File (wordlist.dict), Left Side
Guess.Mod........: Mask (?d?d?d?l?l?l?l?l?d?d?d) [11], Right Side
Guess.Queue.Base.: 1/1 (100.00%)
Guess.Queue.Mod..: 1/1 (100.00%)
Speed.#1.........:        2 H/s (0.47ms) @ Accel:128 Loops:32 Thr:1 Vec:8
Recovered........: 0/1 (0.00%) Digests, 0/1 (0.00%) Salts
Progress.........: 129/35644128000000 (0.00%)
Rejected.........: 0/129 (0.00%)
Restore.Point....: 0/3 (0.00%)
Restore.Sub.#1...: Salt:0 Amplifier:43-44 Iteration:32000-32032
Candidates.#1....: dog360verin123 -> cat360verin123
```

As we see this is not yet correct, as the candidates generate prior the mask. So this needs some more tweaking.
Masks you can define specific characters as well, for instance:

```
hashcat -m 9600 -a 3 doc_pass_hash.txt ?d?d?dhorse?d?d?d --username -o cracked_pass.txt --force

Session..........: hashcat
Status...........: Cracked
Hash.Type........: MS Office 2013
Hash.Target......: $office$*2013*100000*256*16*e77e386a8e68462d2a0a703...69fcf4
Time.Started.....: Sat May 30 17:24:32 2020 (28 secs)
Time.Estimated...: Sat May 30 17:25:00 2020 (0 secs)
Guess.Mask.......: ?d?d?dhorse?d?d?d [11]
Guess.Queue......: 1/1 (100.00%)
Speed.#1.........:       18 H/s (8.21ms) @ Accel:128 Loops:32 Thr:1 Vec:8
Recovered........: 1/1 (100.00%) Digests, 1/1 (100.00%) Salts
Progress.........: 512/1000000 (0.05%)
Rejected.........: 0/512 (0.00%)
Restore.Point....: 0/100000 (0.00%)
Restore.Sub.#1...: Salt:0 Amplifier:0-1 Iteration:99968-100000
Candidates.#1....: 123horse123 -> 112horse778

cat cracked_pass.txt
$office$*2013*100000*256*16*e77e386a8e68462d2a0a703718febbc9*08ee275ccf4946ae0e5922e9ff3114b7*0ab5fc00964f7ed4be9e45c77a33b441b2c4874d28e4bc30f38e99bfb169fcf4:123horse123
```

Cracked password in the end of the file: **123horse123**

There is more to be read about rules and cracking with increased password lenght (--incremental) and combined attacks, but you get the idea.

Here are the official basic examples to get you started:

```
- [ Basic Examples ] -

  Attack-          | Hash- |
  Mode             | Type  | Example command
 ==================+=======+==================================================================
  Wordlist         | $P$   | hashcat -a 0 -m 400 example400.hash example.dict
  Wordlist + Rules | MD5   | hashcat -a 0 -m 0 example0.hash example.dict -r rules/best64.rule
  Brute-Force      | MD5   | hashcat -a 3 -m 0 example0.hash ?a?a?a?a?a?a
  Combinator  

 | MD5   | hashcat -a 1 -m 0 example0.hash example.dict example.dict
```

Comment: For the passwords encrypted with MS Office ⇐ 2003 MD5 + RC4, oldoffice$0, oldoffice$1 hashing algorithm (which is classified as 9710 on hashcat website), Hashcat only allows defining a mask exactly 5 characters long. My question is is it even possible to crack it if the password is more than 5 characters long? Because in my case, currently I don't know the length of the password and it might be more that 5 characters long.

Comment: [Here you can also see how RC4 is limited] (https://notsosecure.com/maximum-password-length-reached/#:~:text=The%20limit%20rose%20from%20a,been%20taken%20from%20hashcat's%20FAQ.&text=There%20are%20also%20attack%2Dmode,affect%20password%20lengths%20in%20hashcat.)